# Realtek RTL8821CE driver 5.5.2.1: wireless option is gone from settings randomly after reboot

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, realtek

I have an ASUS Vivobook model M712D, Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.13.0-37, Realtek rtl8821ce with 5.5.2.1 driver.

The wireless option in Settings disappears randomly after reboot. Rebooting does not fix the problem. If I boot into Windows 10 and then return to Ubuntu, it miraculously reappears. This gets to be tiresome. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$ dkms status

rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1, 5.13.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1, 5.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed

$ uname -r:

5.13.0-37-generic
```

Comment: Is "Fast Startup" disabled in Windows?

Comment: +1 for Fast Boot. Please check here: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: @Nmath : thanks for the quick response. Disabling 'Fast Startup' is one of the first things I do on a new machine. Not doing so makes Linux unable to mount the NTFS volume as writable. I spend most of my time in  Linux. Note that the problem only occurs when shutting down/rebooting from Linux back into Linux. Booting into Windows and back to Linux actually is what fixes the problem. The fact that it happens randomly is what gets me. If it simply failed I could then diagnose the problem. Kind of feels like maybe it's a timimg issue.

Comment: @chili555 : Thanks, See my response to Nmath above.